# How to correctly use an Avenir Airsource One bicycle pump

Tags: pump, inflation

I have an [Avenir Air-Source One pump](http://www.avenirusa.com/parts-and-accessories/pumps/) that keeps popping off while trying to inflate the tires. can someone tell me how to correctly inflate the tires, without the pump popping off?

Comment: Can you tell us which sort of valves your tyres have, and what sort of rims your wheels have? If they are deep v-section rims then that could explain the problem.

Comment: Often pumps have a lever or screw head to adjust the tightness or clamp them on. Could you post a photo?

Comment: I've had problems with a presta valve and these universal heads.  You have to push the pump head ridiculously far down over the valve stem, so the pump head closes around the thicker part of the valve stem.  Sounds to me like the head isn't clamping on properly.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

That appears to be a standard flip-up chuck, and it claims to be "universal".  If using on a Schrader valve you just push it on and flip up the lever.  If using on a Presta valve you unscrew the knob on the Presta valve first, then push on and flip up the lever.

With some of these you need to not push the chuck quite all the way on if using on Schrader.

On the other hand, if the tube is fully deflated, you may need to press the tire with your thumb to hold the valve in place (keep it from sliding back through the rim) as you press the chuck on, so that you can get the chuck on far enough to hold.  (My suspicion is that this is your problem -- the valve is sliding into the rim so the chuck does not get on far enough.)

If need be, you can sometimes tighten the nut around the chuck opening to achieve a tighter fit (or loosen if the fit seems too tight).